# Comportamiento indeterminado de un iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

Tengo definido 4 frames en una página, y desde un frame actualizo el otro, por ejemplo desde el frame iframe-ppal actualizo el iframe-Unit, lo cual funciona divinamente siempre, pero cuando trato de actualizar el iframe-activ desde el ifram-Unit no funciona siempre, de hecho la mayoría de las veces no me actualiza el iframe-activ. He probado colocando la información en los otros frames (frames[0] hasta frames[2]), y cuando lo hago así funciona perfectamente, pero yo necesito que se vea la información en el iframe_activ, no el los otros.

¿alguien tiene una idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

La definición de los frames es de la siguiente manera:

```
<html><head><meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache"><meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache"><meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0"><title>STP Index</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Themes/BlueNote/Style.css">

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFF7" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#FF0000" class="CobaltPageBODY">
<p>
<table bordercolor="#330099" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="#330099" cellpadding="1" width="50%" bordercolorlight="#330099" border="3">
  <tr valign="top" align="left">
    <td>
      <table >
        <tr><td>
      <iframe src="menu.html" height="200" width="750" style="border:none;" name="iframe_menu"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr><td>
      <iframe src="" height="500" width="750" style="border:none;" name="iframe_Unit" id="iframe_Unit" SCROLLING="no"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <table >
        <tr><td>
       <iframe src="./login.php" height="400" width="570" style="border:none;" name="iframe_ppal" id="iframe_ppal"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
      <tr><td>
    <iframe src="" height="300" width="570" style="border:none;" name="iframe_activ" id="iframe_activ"></iframe>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table> </td>  
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde un archivo .php, que se carga en el iframe_Unit, hago el siguiente código para cargar datos en el iframe_activ:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
 echo "window.parent.frames[3].location.href = './home_act.php?id=";
 echo $ListUnit["records"][0]['unit_id'];
 echo "';</script>";
```

Comment: ¿por qué utilizas iframe para poner un menú?. ¿por que no utilizar un archivo php para poner dentro tu menú?. y así llamar a tu menú con un include.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor has el [tour] para hacerte a una idea de cómo funcionamos. Y no sobra que consultes [ask] para familiarizarte con el modelo de preguntas. En cuanto a tu pregunta actual te puedo decir que el script se ejecuta cuando la página que carga en iframe_Unit ha sido cargada (ya que no hay condiciones de control) de modo que el DOM no necesariamente está completo y en tal caso **frames[3]** aún no existe efectivamente en todos los casos. Eso provoca que unas veces cargue y otras no. Carga cuando el DOM esté completo antes de ejecutar el script (lo veo difícil)

Comment: Gracias, quevedo, edité la pregunta para corregirla un poco. Entiendo lo que me indicas, sin embargo no se me ocurre cómo puedo corregirlo.